# Replacing a string with another string in all the database mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database which I want to export to `CSV` File.

In one of the fields ringPics, I have values as

```
"abc.png,zxc.png"
```

Now when I export to CSV it mix up columns.

Since the database is very big , i can't replace `,` manually.

I want to do something like this
replace `,` with `/\`

What changes need to be done with below query

```
UPDATE `rings` SET `ringPicDir`= REPLACE("ringPicDir", ',', '/\')
```

Comment: So where is the problem ? `UPDATE rings SET ringPicDir= REPLACE(ringPicDir, ',', '/\\')`

Comment: what happens when you try your update query ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
 UPDATE `rings` SET `ringPicDir`= REPLACE( ringPicDir, ',', '/\')
                                         ^^^---no quotes here , you can use backticks also
```

or this

```
UPDATE `rings` SET `ringPicDir` = if (ringPicDir Like '%,%' ,  REPLACE( ringPicDir, ',', '/\'), ringPicDir)
```

Comment: UPDATE rings SET ringPicDir= REPLACE(ringPicDir, ',', '/\\')  worked Corrupt answer.